# Changing Bootstrap nav-item active class (of dropdown) within Django

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, django-views, bootstrap-4

For some reason Django blocks aren't properly extending 'active' for me.

So this works in base.html:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown active">
```

But this doesn't:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown {% block 'index_active' %}{% endblock %}">
```

An example of my index or about html:

```
{% extends "client_side_app/base.html" %}

{% block index_active %}
    active
{% endblock %}
```

What's odd about this is that I have content blocks right below this above code that have no problem injecting the html into the base.html.

Any idea as to why this is happening? :(

Thanks,

Dev

PS - I came to [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028673/changing-active-class-in-bootstrap-navbar-not-staying-in-inherited-django-templa/51911275#51911275) first and tried implementing javascript and basically came to the same issue to the guy asking the question. I essentially tried both ways to no avail, and a lot of other things to boot.

Comment: can i see they way you have imported bootstrap in your codes ?

Answer (score 2):

The block names don't match. `index_active` is defined in `base.html` but `about_active` is used in the sub-template.

Comment: Also there's no need of quotes in `'index_active'`.

Comment: The block names did match, sorry. I was just showing you an example of the code from each one of templates as an example of how it connected back to the base. I'll correct that now. At any rate, guillermo was right. It was because there was no need of quotes in 'index_active'